# Is there a way to make a folder-like hierarchy in redis cache?

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-web-api, redis

So I'm using redis cache in my c# webapi and being able to implement a similar hierarchy would make my life much easier (something like this:

```
a-> key1
    b-> c ->key2
            key3
        d ->...
```

)

My other option is to make a tree like approach with keys where a would give me 2 other keys one for key and another for b and so one (but would be a mess)

Comment: what sort of  volume are we talking about here? or to put it another way: would it be sufficient just to store a JSON clob? what operations do you need to perform?

Comment: @MarcGravell I want to have one cache for every client but every client have more than one tenant, so I would like to have something like tenantusers> t1users> list of jsons users and so on .

EDIT : keeping in mind that I have some client information thats on a higher level than the tenants ( common for all tenants)

Comment: and with that passing "list of jsons users" remark, my ReJSON answer looks even more appropriate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis supports multiple datatypes. For your case you can use a [`Hashes`](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#Hashes) since a hash can have another nested hash in it.

Since Redis doesn't support nested data structure, you can store it this way by storing the inner hash reference in outer hash which will have difficulty while retrieving the data back. Else, you can create the hierarchical object structure as a JSON (Or, if you already have one) and store that serialized object in Redis.

See [Storing nested objects in Redis](https://alexandergugel.svbtle.com/storing-relational-data-in-redis)

Comment: yeah I guess this will be the closest to what I need. Thanks!

Comment: "since a hash can have another nested hash in it" - no it can't; a hash is strictly name/value, where "value" here is a clob/blob. This will not allow you to create a hierarchical structure.

Comment: @MarcGravell I mean you can store the reference of the other hash

Comment: @Rahul you can store the *key*, sure; but then a: you need a way of disambiguating between keys and values (leaf nodes vs branch nodes), and b: you need a way of *navigating* and *iterating* the hierarchy, neither of which is obvious / easy here

Answer (score 14):

If you use redis commander to view your cache, you can use keys separated with colons,e.g,   set1:subset:subset:key.   Its not really a hierarchy but it displays like folders in the commander view.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do here is somewhat outside of what redis *wants* you to do. You can *fake it* with nesting keys inside keys (perhaps via a hash), but it will be *really hard to work with*.

However! This might be a good fit for a redis "module" (requires redis 4.*). In particular, I wonder whether [ReJSON](http://rejson.io/) might be a good fit. This is *designed* for JSON usage, but frankly: JSON is a hierarchical nested key/value data type - exactly what you want. Just overlook the JSON part :)

In particular, ReJSON allows you to query, access, and manipulate arbitrary nodes via a syntax that will be familiar if you've ever used XPath.

How to access ReJSON will depend on what client library you are using. If you're using SE.Redis, you will probably want to use the `db.Execute(command, args)` method (since I don't have ReJSON bindings natively exposed). If you're using a "cluster" topology, make sure that the *key* is passed as a `RedisKey` (rather than as a `string`), so that it knows how to route it.